# how to add active profile to spring in conjuction with spring's spring.profiles.active

Tags: spring, web, servletcontextlistener, spring-profiles

We do have some spring profiles enables via web.xml spring.profiles.active and I want to leave it that way as this is the way for our deployment team to activate profiles.
in addition I want to activate some more profiles based on the presence of properties files. so I added an ApplicationContextInitializer

```
public class WecaApplicationContextInitializer implements
    ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>{
@Override
public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    applicationContext.getEnvironment().addActiveProfile("someprofile");
}
```

but then spring ignores the spring.profiles.active context param and does not load my main profiles.

anyone has an idea how to do it?

I think I can add a ServletContextListener and add a profile to spring.profiles.active param but I think this is kind of ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use:

```
profiles = ac.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()
```

To get active profiles, then add to these and pass into:

```
ac.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(profiles, "profileName")
```